# How to iterate function on multiple objects with certain keyword in obj name?

Tags: javascript

How to iterate thru objects that have "Device" in object name (IE: Device_0, Device_1, Device_2, etc.) performing "DeviceMonitor" updating function on each device object found every 1/4 second.

I know this is first-grade stuff for you all, but having to act only if the object name has a certain keyword and do it only every quarter second as to not a slow program running down, is too complicated for me figure out being a newbie. Currently, I have Device Objects _0 thru _10, but more could be added in the future, below is an example of each type of object and function code I want to run every quarter of a second.

This is to more efficiently simulate an electrical circuit. I have a working model with spaghetti code, but over a thousand lines of code, the above will be a much better approach if I can get it working as described.

```
   Wire_1 = 118.64;
   Wire_2;
   Wire_4 = Wire_3; 
   Wire_6 = Wire_5;
   Wire_8 = Wire_7;
   Wire_9;
   Wire_10;
   Neutral_4 = Neutral_3;
   Neutral_2 = Neutral_1 = 1;

   var Device_0 = new Object();
   Device_0.InputWire = Wire_1;
   Wire_2 = Device_0.OutputWire; 
   Device_0.model = "ConnectorDevice";
   Device_0.name= 'Fuse 1';
   Device_0.OnOff = 1;  
   Device_0.MinVoltage = 0; 
   Device_0.FailedDevice = 0;
   Device_0.IntermittentDevice = 0;

   var Device_3 = new Object();
   Device_3.InputWire = Wire_9;
   Neutral_3 = Device_3.OutputWire; 
   Device_3.model = "OutputDevice";
   Device_3.name= 'RunningLamp';
   Device_3.OnOff = 0;  
   Device_3.MinVoltage = 60; 
   Device_3.FailedDevice = 0;
   Device_3.IntermittentDevice = 0;

   var Device_5 = new Object();
   Device_5.InputWire = Wire_5;
   Wire_8 = Device_5.OutputWire; 
   Device_5.model = "SwitchDevice";
   Device_5.name= 'RunSwitch';
   Device_5.OnOff = 0;  
   Device_5.MinVoltage = 0; 
   Device_5.FailedDevice = 0;
   Device_5.IntermittentDevice = 0;

   function DeviceMonitor(DeviceNumber) {

   if (DeviceNumber.model === "OutputDevice") {
        if (DeviceNumber.InputWire > DeviceNumber.MinVoltage && !DeviceNumber.FailedDevice && !DeviceNumber.IntermittentDevice) {
            DeviceNumber.OnOff = 1;
        } else {
            DeviceNumber.OnOff = 0;
        }

    }

    if (DeviceNumber.model === "SwitchDevice") {
        if (DeviceNumber.FailedDevice || DeviceNumber.IntermittentDevice){
            DeviceNumber.OutputWire = 0;
        } else if (DeviceNumber.OnOff){
        DeviceNumber.OutputWire = DeviceNumber.InputWire;
        }

    }

    if (DeviceNumber.model === "ConnectorDevice") {
        if (DeviceNumber.FailedDevice || DeviceNumber.IntermittentDevice){
            DeviceNumber.OutputWire = 0;
        } else {
        DeviceNumber.OutputWire = DeviceNumber.InputWire;
        }
    }

    if (DeviceNumber.model === "Transformer") {

    }

}
```

Ideally, to reduce processing time, it would be even better if it would only run update function if any property of monitored objects, changed. But that would be even more complicated. So just looking to do every 1.4 second.

Comment: You can't iterate through arbitrary variables by name, but you can create an array `var array = [Device_0, Device_3, Device_5];` and iterate that. There's a _lot_ of stuff you could simplify here but you haven't asked about anything else so I'll try not to overwhelm you with other suggestions.

Comment: You can make a `devices` array. If you know how many devices you will have, then you can instantiate the array with that many default device objects, then loop through them to change only the values that need to be changed.

Comment: One other thing I will point out though is that your `if` statements are erroneously using the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) instead of the [identity operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity).